# Unknown symbol - how to create it with Latex

Tags: symbols

I'm searching for a way to create the attached character in LaTeX. It's not the one that is created with `\mathbb{R}`as this creates double strokes for each line and not just the leading one.

The image is taken from a pdf-file, which was created with MiKTeX, but I do not have access to the source. When I copy it to Word I can only get a capital R, without double strokes.

Thank you very much.

[image: R with double vertical stroke]

Comment: just for the record, there is no difference in *meaning* (that i am aware or) between the different styles of double-stroked (blackboard bold) letters.  the preference for a particular style is subjective.  if your paper is submitted for publication, the publisher may have a preferred "house style".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to find the answer.

```
\usepackage{dsfont}
\mathds{R}
```

Use this in math mode.

[image: Result]

Comment: I did not know this website, but that's it! I can get the character I am searching for. Thank you!

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche We had both edited it at the same time. I have taken the freedom to add the image.